# Activate feature using feature name in C#

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, development, features

I deployed a feature creating a new feature item in Visual Studio. I'm currently using SharePoint 2013. 
I'm trying to activate this feature in C# by using the feature name. I need to activate it programmatically because I need to have it on more subsites.

```
var features = web.Features;
```

If I try to use the `features.Add` method I can only use a GUID but I need to activate the feature by using the name because the name is all I have. 
How can I do it? There's a way? 
I think I might use the `features.FeatureDefinitions` method in order to get all the features but when I use it I get an empty collection everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

You can use SPFarm.Local.FeatureDefinitions[featureName] for Web features

```
// Look for feature definition using feature name
SPFeatureDefinition featureDefinition = SPFarm.Local.FeatureDefinitions[featureName];

// Look for activated feature
SPFeature feature = web.Features.Cast().FirstOrDefault(f => f.DefinitionId == featureDefinition.Id);

// Deactivate feature if activated
if (feature != null)
{
    try
    {
        web.Features.Remove(feature.DefinitionId);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    { 
    }
}
else
{
    // Activate feature
    try
    {
        web.Features.Add(featureDefinition.Id);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {     
    }
}
```

Comment: @Gautam Sheth : For "web.Features", not able to resolve 'web'. which dll should I include...?? I am using it for SharePoint online.

Comment: @Koder101 - can you ask a separate question, will be able to explain in more detail there ? the above code wont work in SharePoint online.